# How Can i Make Android Sensor effect like this..?

Tags: android, sensors

i am a student and recently i have seen a [video of iphone application was this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LV-RvzXGH2Y)

in this he **just blow air from mouth (sorry dont know exact word hope u understand)** and gets sensor event..i think its Pressure type sensor and i am searching for this in android from last couple of days..

WHICH TYPE OF SENSOR CAN BE USED IN ANDROID TO DO SAME?

if anybudy know whats that exactly..and which type of sensor can be used to do same in android ..please let me know..

anykind of tutorial..demo will be highly appreciated..!

Thank You for Reading the question.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on watching the video, I do not think he was using any type of pressure sensor. By blowing on the microphone (which is what he is doing) it would generate a "noise" to the microphone sensor. He is, most likely, responding to that noise.

Comment: ok..thanks now i will search that way and try to find if this is the way..will let u know if i found anything but there is no specific type defined in Sensor class like microphone

Answer (score 0):

this is a tutorial that describes doing the same thing 
but on ios
and as @JasCav said sound processing is the best "if not the only" way to do it

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/